# Must Declare Scalar variable "@ZeroQty"

Tags: sql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

having scalar problem when saving a record produces the error
this is the code that i have

```
    Try
        ' Dim updatedb As String = " INSERT tblStock SET StockCode = @StockCode,SupplierRef = @SupplierRef,Season = @Season,DeadCode = @DeadCode,DeliveredQtyHangers = @DeliveredQtyHangers,RemoveFromClearance = @RemoveFromClearance,AmountTaken= @AmountTaken, CostValue = @CostValue,PCMarkUp = @PCMarkUp,ZeroQty= @ZeroQty,CreatedBy = @CreatedBy,CreatedDate= @CreatedDate WHERE StockCode = @StockCode"
        Dim insertdb As String = " INSERT INTO tblStock (StockCode,SupplierRef,Season,DeadCode,RemoveFromClearance,AmountTaken,DeliveredQtyHangers,CostValue,PCMarkUp,ZeroQty,CreatedBy,CreatedDate)VALUES(@StockCode,@SupplierRef, @Season, @DeadCode,@RemoveFromClearance,@AmountTaken,@DeliveredQtyHangers,@CostValue,@PCMarkUp,@ZeroQty,@CreatedBy,@CreatedDate)"
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=StockMasterv2;Trusted_Connection=True"
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        ' Create a DataSet
        Me.Validate()
        Dim com As New SqlCommand(insertdb, connection)
        com.Connection.Open()
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockCode", TextBox1.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierRef", TextBox2.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Season", cboSeasons.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeadCode", CheckBox1.CheckState)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RemoveFromClearance", CheckBox2.CheckState)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountTaken", TextBox3.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZeroQty,", CheckBox3.CheckState)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostValue", TextBox4.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCMarkUp", TextBox5.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", TextBox6.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTimePicker1.Value)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveredQtyHangers", TextBox7.Text)
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        com.Connection.Close()
        Form1.DataViewer.Refresh()
        MsgBox("Record Created Successfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Stock Master v2")
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox("Update Failed because of" & vbCrLf & ex.ErrorCode & "  " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Stock Master v2")
    End Try
End Sub
```

i know its long also when using the insert command its not saving to the database if there is only text boxes and combo boxes

Comment: Instead of `CheckState` you should use the `Checked` property. Though not sure if that would solve your problem.

Comment: Why do you have a comma in `AddWithValue("@ZeroQty,", `? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra comma at the end of your variable in the `AddWithValue`

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZeroQty,", CheckBox3.CheckState)
                                     ^---Here
```

Remove that, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to `UPDATE` in your first SQL statement?

```
" UPDATE tblStock SET StockCode....
```

Also maybe you should try setting the variable `@ZeroQty` value to

```
CheckBox3.CheckState.ToString()
```

Comment: This should be just a comment since the line of code you are referring isn't part of the problem presented.

Comment: the first one is commented out so that i can copy and past into other forms and functions of the application